Staging Ground review action buttons display error when browser window is not maximized
As shown in the following picture, when the browser window is not maximized, Staging Ground review action buttons' CSS overflows.

This happens on:

Firefox 115.14.0esr (64-bit) on Windows 11
Google Chrome 121.0.6167.86 (64 bit) on Windows 10

It displays fine on:

Chromium 125.0.6422.142(Official Build, ungoogled-chromium) (64-bit) on Windows 11


I can't reproduce this in up-to-date Firefox on Linux. Even if you want to stick with ESR versions, you really should update to 128.1.

@KarlKnechtel Oh, I didn't notice that. I downloaded my firefox esr with this just two months ago. About Firefox says 115.14.0esr (64-bit) is up to date version. When I go to All Firefox ESR downloads, I see two choices from Which version would you like?: 115.14.0esr and 128.1.0esr. The release note of former is later than latter.

I can reproduce it with Firefox on Linux (without plugins/user scripts, Firefox 129.0 on Ubuntu 24.04 (Wayland)) but both the vertical and horizontal window size must be limited.

I can reproduce this on Waterfox G6.0.18 (64-bit), Windows 10: GIF demonstration. I had to re-enable the left navigation panel. This bug does not seem to be related to the window being maximized (open the inspection panel in a maximized window and start resizing it) or not. Instead (I think...), it's about the review actions panel (when at the bottom) not limiting itself to the SG post, and expanding beyond that to overlay the left navigation panel. This is with and without extensions.

This has now been fixed! You'd think it would be something easy like setting the correct z-index, but it was something weird involving stacking contexts due to us setting position: sticky incorrectly in some cases.



Before
After









